# How hierarchical routing would work in this case?

Tags: routing, router, protocol-theory

I have the following AS-level topology with 3 ASes, i.e., A, B and C.

[image]

I am asked to

> illustrate the idea of hierarchical routing in the particular case of the Internet by describing the process by which an IP packet would be routed from a source router `X` in `A` to a destination router `Y` in . Moreover, for each step, I should briefly describe which routing information is used, which protocol determines that routing information, and how routing information is transmitted to the router.

I know that within an AS there's a internal routing protocol. The most common ones are link-state or distance-vector-based protocols. OSPF (open-shortest path protocol) is a link-state based routing protocol that is quite used nowadays. Another one apparently is IS-IS.  A common, if I am not wrong, old distance-vector based protocol is RIP (routing information protocol).

There are then external routing protocols, which are protocols that allow ASes to communicate. The most common one is BGP (border gateway protocol).

Of course from one router `X` to send something to another router `Y` in a different AS these two kind of protocols (internal and external) should be used.

I think that the `GW`s are border routers that allow the ASes to communicate. My understanding is that `X` should first send its packet to `GW1` using `A`'s internal routing protocol. Then `GW1` would contact `GW2` using for example `BGP`, and the packet would then be transferred to `GW3` (using e.g. RIP), and then from `GW3` to `GW4` using again maybe BGP. Once arrived at `GW4`, again, another internal routing protocol, such as OSPF, would be used to send `A`'s original packet to `Y`.

Apart from that, I don't think I would be able to give an exhaustive answer to the question above.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think the subject is too broad. Please try to formulate specific questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If AS'es A,B,C are all you have:

1. Both AS A and AS C could use static default routing towards AS B.
2. AS B could point specific static route X to A and specific static route Y to C.
3. No dynamic routing protocol between AS'es.
4. AS B could run OSPF between GW2 and GW3.

This could be thought as if AS B would lie in a routing level hierarchically "above" both AS A and AS C.